# how to store chechbox value in php

Tags: php

I have checkbox of condition apply where I want to store string value "Condtion Apply".
But, I get inserted error so give solution how to store value in database

Comment: Checking the _POST['value'] and storing it as you wish did not help?

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant code ...

Answer (score 2):

HTML could be something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="condapply"/> Apply to conditions
```

In case you don't check the checkbox there will be no transmitted POST-variable after you clicked the submit-button.

So on the other side (php) you should use something like:

```
// evalutes if the value has been set
$dbval = isset($_POST['condapply']) ? '1' : '0';
```

$dbval will always contain some ready-to-store-in-db value. In this case eigther '1' or '0'.

Comment: You can simplify $dbval = isset($_POST['condapply']) ? '1' : '0'; to $dbval = (int)isset($_POST['condapply']);

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

-- php --
$food = $_POST['food'];
-- end php --

-- html --
form method="post" action="?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"

Please choose type of residence::
Steak:input type="checkbox" value="Steak" name="food[]">:

input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
/form>
-- end html --

You might need to correct the syntax of the code in order to work correctly. the tags.
after you get the value to the $food variable (this will be an array() )
you can update to the db.