# How to grab checkbox value as integer and not string?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to store chechbox value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642391/how-to-store-chechbox-value-in-php)

Here is my code:

`<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" value="3" />`

And this gets passed as:

`array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" }`

But I would rather like it to be integer. Is this possible?

Comment: In PHP a variable does not need to be of a specific type and can freely move between types as demanded by the code it is being used in.

Comment: @NullPointer It's my question in your link... Now after you edited - it's absolutely not the same or even related.

Comment: @Paul oops now its possible duplicate of my link

Comment: i think http://stackoverflow.com/a/1642536/1723893 this answer will help you

Comment: It's due to the html form specification and the transport via http/s that you get the values as string. every serverside script has to deal with this, regardless of the programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast value as

```
$string = '3';
$int = (int) $string;
// or
$int = intval($string);
// or check 
if(is_numeric($string)) {}
if(ctype_digit($string)) {}
```

update

```
php > $string = '10000000000000';
php > var_dump($string);
string(14) "10000000000000"
php > var_dump((int)$string);
int(10000000000000)
php > var_dump(intval($string));
int(10000000000000)
```

Comment: Will this always convert numbers well? I want it to do 3 => 3, 1000000000000 => 1000000000000 and not 1000000000000 => 2147483647.

Comment: Thanks :) The best examples and checks in this answer.

Comment: maximum supported value will be `PHP_INT_MAX`, which is the largest integer supported in this build of PHP. Usually int(2147483647). Available since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5 :)

Comment: In order to work with arbitrary length integers [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You will only get string and you need to convert it into integer

you can use
`$value = intval('3');`

So `$value` will have int value 3.

Comment: "intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647" from php.net - I don't want it to happen.

Comment: if you have to use such huge numbers, use float / double

Answer (score 1):

If value always is a integer as string simply cast:

```
$zahl = (int)$value
```

Comment: Missing the `$` before `value`

Comment: True. My backspace was to fast :D

Answer (score 0):

Values of `$_POST` array are always strings or arrays.

One can use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function to get integer value of string, like this:

```
$int_val = intval($_POST['name'][0]);
```

or you can cast to integer like this:

```
$int_val = (int) ($_POST['name'][0]);
```